# Show a simple, no loop, 3 connected graph for which $\min(\deg(v))> \text { edge connectivity } > \text {vertex- connectivity }$

Tags: graph-theory

**QUESTION**

> Show a simple, no loop, 3 connected graph for which $\min(\deg(v))> \text { edge connectivity } > \text {vertex- connectivity}$.

**Attempt**

I tried going from a wheel (which are 3 connected) and adding some random vertices and edges all around but I couldn't get it to work. Then I started with some different complete graphs, which didn't help either.

Could you give me some tips on how to construct a graph of this type? More generally, what if the question asks for a $n$-connected graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following works:

with minimum degree $5$, edge connectivity $4$ and vertex connectivity $3$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the graph must be 3-connected aswell. (Could you tell me what software you used to make that neat picture?)

Comment: Oh, my bad. I made it with geogebra.

Comment: I think this graph works. Please double check though.

Comment: Holy damn, I'm almost sure it works! How'd you come up with that? Thank you a lot!!

Comment: I started by placing the three vertices that where going to form the cut-set and then I tried a lot of stuff.

Comment: So instead of K7, can we use Kn for any n?